# Having one slow rabbit mq consumer slows down other consumer

Tags: rabbitmq

I have one rabbit mq Publisher who is publishing on a Direct exchange. There are multiple rabbit mq consumers bound to the Direct exchange with different routing keys.

Few of these consumers might take more time to process the message.

My question is does one slow consumer affect the performance of other consumers even though they are bound on different routing keys ?

Answer (score 1):

One slow consumer will have no affect on other consumers.  Each consumer is independent and can work as fast or as slow as necessary for your application.

Answer (score 1):

It will affect other consumers in the terrible case that said consumer's queue start backing up badly up to the point where you hit the server memory watermark. If that happens tho, you need to review what's going on in your system for such situation to arise.